# Running Python script from .BAT file, taking .BAT Filename as input

Tags: python, windows, file, batch-file

I got a Python script (test1.py) I need to run with a bat file (render.bat).

Question 1:

First, I had a definition in my test1.py and it always failed to run, nothing happened. Can someone kindly explain why?

```
import os
def test01 :
   os.system('explorer')
```

and in the bat file:

```
python c:/test01.py
```

but as soon as I removed the def it worked. I just want to learn why this happened.

Question 2:

How can I take "render" string from render.bat as a string input for my python script so I can run something like :

```
import os
def test1(input) :
   os.system("explorer " + input)
```

So the "input" is taken from the .BAT filename?

Answer (score 0):

1. Functions don't actually do anything unless you call them. Try putting `test01()` at the end of the script.
2. `%0` will give you the *full* name of the batch file called, including the `.bat`. Stripping it will probably be easier in Python than in the batch file.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Number 1 works perfectly. for 2nd question, what command in my python script I should use to capture %0 ? Thanks again

Comment: I'd pass it as an argument, caught via `sys.argv`.

Answer (score 0):

**Question1:** Keyword def in python defines a function. However, to use a function you have to explicitly call it, i.e.

```
import os
def test01(): # do not forget ()
   os.system('explorer')

test01() # call the function
```

Answer (score 0):

1) You have to actually `call` the functions to achieve your task.

2) `%0` refers to the running script. Therefor create a `test.bat file` like

```
@ echo off
echo %0
```

Output = `test.bat`

You can strip the `.bat` extension from the output.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Number 1 works perfectly. for 2nd question, what command in my python script I should use to capture %0 ? Thanks again

Comment: @user1328167: You should use `sys.argv`.